# What is wrong with this objective-c, passing data from one view to another IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to assign a value to a string variable on a UITableViewController that I push on to my navigationController.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
// now you can use cell.textLabel.text
NSMutableString *v = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[v setString:cell.textLabel.text];

DCAArtistViewController *dvController = [[DCAArtistViewController alloc] init];


if ([v isEqual:@"UK"]) {

    dvController.st =@"75";

}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
```

I have tried

```
[dvController.st setString:@"75"];
```

On the view that is loaded I have an NSLog which always shows null.

```
 NSLog(@"The st is%@",st);
```

What am I doing wrong?  the examples I have seen show assigning to a property on a viewcontroller like this dvController.st =@"75";

The DCAArtistViewController .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface DCAArtistViewController : UITableViewController{

NSString *st;
NSMutableArray *aa;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfItemss;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *st;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *aa;

@end
```

This is the start of the DCAArtistViewController (The view that is loaded)

```
@implementation DCAArtistViewController
@synthesize listOfItemss;
@synthesize st;
@synthesize aa;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {

    aa = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"The st is%@",st);
    NSLog(@"The self st is%@",st);
```

Comment: Are you sure that 'v' is equal to UK? If so, show how you setup your 'st' property on the DCArtistViewController class.

Comment: yes definitely I have stepped through the code in the debugger and it hits the corresponding if statement based on what is selected on the table.  I just show UK for simplicity.  V does match ok and the view loads.

Comment: Can you provide some code for DCAArtistViewController, as in the declaration of the property `st`, and where it might be changed in the .m?

Comment: I have setup "st" as NSString *st; in the @@interface section and I have @@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *st; also

Comment: Try using isEqualToString:. It also matters where this code is placed, what triggers it, etc.  Have you set break points to see if cell is nil? and if not, cell.textLabel.text ?  Look at these things, make sure v is what you think it is.  Then make sure your property is defined and synthesized properly.  EDIT: Just saw a bunch of new comments... did you synthesize it?  Are there build warnings?

Comment: `st` is only being used in NSLog on the view that is loaded

Comment: Please read the NSMutableString class reference to see what this class is good for. All you need is

Comment: I updated the code above to show the start of the .m file , i will try using the isEqualToString and update

Comment: I added an NSLog for string `v` -  `NSLog(@"what is v > %@",v);`  and it prints **what is v > UK**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple. You are logging `st` in your `init` method. But you don't set the `st` property until after the `init` method is called.

Comment: This is correct.  Try logging it in viewDidLoad, or viewWillAppear.  Also, I would try and use better variable names.  If your application/class grows, these names will not be very helpful.

Comment: I moved the code to viewDidLoad and it shows the value correctly passed, thanks guys was wrecking my head all night,

Comment: excellent @rmaddy , by passing that value across to the loaded view it correctly loads the table list for each country.  Progress

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. In your header file, you have both:

```
@interface DCAArtistViewController : UITableViewController{
    NSString *st;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *st;
```

This means technically you are declaring two variables, named locally as `_st` and `st` (`_st` is managed by the generated getter/setter for the property)

When setting your string, you're technically setting it to `-st`, as you're using the `.` notation within `dvController.st =@"75";`. When using the `NSLog`, you're trying to print out `st`.

**Solution:** Delete `NSString* st` from your interface, you don't need it if you also have a property. Within the `NSLog`, use either `NSLog(@"The st is%@",_st);` or `NSLog(@"The st is%@",self.st);`

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct. He has an `@synthesize st;` line in the .m file. This assigns the 'st' property to the 'st' ivar. There is no '_st' ivar being created here.

Comment: My bad, I missed the `@synthesize`! Apologies

Comment: No bother , I moved code in the loaded view from the initWithStyle method to viewDidLoad method and it showed the value passed.